# Google Places Autocomplete + Angular2

Tags: angular, google-places-api

I am building a simple Google Places Autocomplete Angular2 directive but the problem is that cannot get any prediction (the response is always empty?!)...

As a proof of concept I created the simplest possible code snippet as a reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_API_KEY]&libraries=places" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="go()">go</button>
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text"></input>
    <script>
    var autocomplete = null;

    function go() {
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
                types: ['geocode']
            });
    }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The above code works - I can get predictions after clicking Go button.

Now, Angular2 scenario:

My _Layout.cshtml file has the following tag in head section:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_API_KEY]&libraries=places" async defer></script>
```

My directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

declare var google: any;

@Directive({ selector: '[googleplaces]' })
export class GooglePlacesDirective {

    autocomplete: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

    }

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            (this.el.nativeElement),
            { types: ['geocode', 'cities'] });
    }
}
```

And simple Angular component:

```
<form [formGroup]="companyForm">
   
    .
    .
    .

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Location">Location</label>
        <input type="text" 
               class="form-control" 
               id="Location" 
               fromControlName="Location" 
               googleplaces>
    </div>
</form>
```

The Scenario 2 (angular) doesn't work. The facts:

- autocomplete is initialized (it has all expected properties/methods, placeholder is "Enter a location", etc...)
- autocomplete doesn't return any prediction for typed search string (it returns only "/**/*xdc*._le3zv3 && *xdc*._le3zv3( [4] )")

Also, Google API Console says everything is as it should be?! Here is the screenshot:

[image: Dashboard screenshot]

What can be in question here? Thanks...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/forms';

declare var google:any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[Googleplace]',
  providers: [NgModel],
  host: {
    '(input)' : 'onInputChange()'
  }
})
export class GoogleplaceDirective {

   @Output() setAddress: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  modelValue:any;
  autocomplete:any;
  private _el:HTMLElement;


  constructor(el: ElementRef,private model:NgModel) {
    this._el = el.nativeElement;
    this.modelValue = this.model;
    var input = this._el;

    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {});
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', ()=> {
      var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      this.invokeEvent(place);

    });
  }

  invokeEvent(place:Object) {
    this.setAddress.emit(place);
  }

  onInputChange() {
    console.log(this.model);
  }
}
```

To use

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" name="Location" [(ngModel)]="address" #LocationCtrl="ngModel"
        Googleplace (setAddress)="getAddressOnChange($event,LocationCtrl)">
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @Habeeb!

Comment: If you get expected result. Please mark as correct answer.
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi Habeeb, I am new to angular 2.. I am trying to add an autocomplete in my page...when I am Searching for an solution I found this post.When "this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {});" this line reach I am getting an error like "InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement"..can u plz hlp me to figure out this error???

Comment: @Girija Have you added <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_API_KEY]&libraries=places" async defer></script>
In your code?

Comment: I had to wrap the call to `this.setAddress.emit(place);` in a `NgZone.run()`: `constructor(private zone: NgZone, ..)` in the constructor, then `this.zone.run(() => {this.setAddress.emit(place);})` in the event listener. Without it some model to UI view synchronization was not triggered immediately

Comment: I am getting InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement  in my maps.google.api.com ...key....

Answer (score 8):

@Habeeb's answer is a great start, but this is a cleaner implementation.  First install the googlemaps typings `npm install --save-dev @types/googlemaps` and import them somewhere in your app `import {} from '@types/googlemaps'`.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  // xx is your app's prefix
  selector: '[xxPlaceLookup]'
})
export class PlaceLookupDirective implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  private element: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.element = el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.element, {
      types: ['establishment'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
      const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      this.onSelect.emit(place);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Cleaner implementation.

Comment: I had to wrap the call to `this.setAddress.emit(place);` in a `NgZone.run()`: `constructor(private zone: NgZone, ..)` in the constructor, then `this.zone.run(() => {this.setAddress.emit(place);})` in the event listener. Without it some model to UI view synchronization was not triggered immediately

Comment: what do you mean by somewhere in your app?