# TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I want to use an Angular 2 Google map autocomplete and I found [this directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341930/google-places-autocomplete-angular2).

When I tried to use it, it gives me this error:

> errors.ts:42 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autocomplete' of undefined

I dont know if I missed something. Anyway, here's the code of the directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/forms';

declare var google:any;

@Directive({
selector: '[Googleplace]',
providers: [NgModel],
host: {
'(input)' : 'onInputChange()'
}
})
export class GoogleplaceDirective {

@Output() setAddress: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
modelValue:any;
 autocomplete:any;
private _el:HTMLElement;


constructor(el: ElementRef,private model:NgModel) {
this._el = el.nativeElement;
this.modelValue = this.model;
var input = this._el;

 this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {});
 google.maps.event.addListener(this.autocomplete, 'place_changed', ()=> {
  var place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
  this.invokeEvent(place);

});
 }

  invokeEvent(place:Object) {
  this.setAddress.emit(place);
}

 onInputChange() {
console.log(this.model);
}
 }
```

Here's how to use it:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" name="Location" [(ngModel)]="address" #LocationCtrl="ngModel"
    Googleplace (setAddress)="getAddressOnChange($event,LocationCtrl)">
```

Comment: Are you sure that `google.maps.places` is defined ?

Comment: thanks for for answer but i just copy the code as it is

Comment: i have to install dependencies??

Comment: You should try to `console.log(google.maps)` and see if it own a `places` attribute before this line : `this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {});`

Comment: it gives me this:{"Animation":{"BOUNCE":1,"DROP":2,"Zo":3,"Uo":4},"ControlPosition":{"TOP_LEFT":1,"TOP_CENTER":2,"TOP":2,"TOP_RIGHT":3,"LEFT_CENTER":4,"LEFT_TOP":5,"LEFT":5,"LEFT_BOTTOM":6,"RIGHT_TOP":7,"RIGHT":7...................(the object is so long)

Comment: You can just copy/paste in text editor, then ctrl + f `places` to see if the property exist in the object.

Comment: it works now ..but it gives me another error

Answer (score 13):

If you are using google maps you have to import the Api in the ngmodule like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      clientId: '<mandatory>',
      //apiVersion: 'xxx', // optional
      //channel: 'yyy', // optional
      //apiKey: 'zzz', // optional
      language: 'en',
      libraries: ['geometry', 'places']
    })
  ],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

the library 'places' is needed to use the autocomplete module.

Than use it like this:

```
    import {MapsAPILoader} from "@agm/core";
    ...
    constructor(private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    ...
        this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
          let autocomplete = new window['google'].maps.places.Autocomplete(..., ...);

          autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => { ...
```

You can take a look here: [Angular 2 + Google Maps Places Autocomplete](http://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/)

Answer (score 3):

This approach helped me to get the rid of this error. Just change the google maps api import to like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY
```

Then add `&libraries=places` to the end of URL so it looks like this:

```
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURAPIKEY&libraries=places">
</script>
```